# React NavLink activeClassName works but regular className stops working on element

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm making a small project with React and I'm implementing a side navigation. I used `NavLink` to make the links. I did some research on `NavLink` and I found out that by using the `activeClassName` property I could set a class for the active link. It works fine but when I want to add a regular class like  `className="link"` to style the not active links. `activeClassName` stops working. Does anyone know why and how I could still use `activeClassName` and a normal class to style `NavLink`.

SideNav.js

```
           <div id="nav-links">
                <NavLink exact={true} to="/" activeClassName="active"  className="link">
                  Calender
              </NavLink>
           </div>
```

scss

```
    #nav-links {
        height: 70%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        .link{
            text-decoration: none;
            color:$black;

            &:hover {
                color: $blue;
            }
        }
    }
.active{
    color: $blue;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct can you create a code sandbox to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: First time making something in sandbox --> https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-meitner-3vtdd?file=/src/App.js . I tried to create it as fast as I could but it is giving errors but I don't know why

Comment: You forgot to `return` in Sidenav.js

Comment: It seems to be working in your sandbox.

Comment: Ow yes indeed I forgot to return. I was in a rush earlier that's why I didn't have the time to properly see what was wrong with it. I've changed the sandbox but I don't see it working. when the navlink is active it the link should be blue but it isn't.